# How to get rows for same column values separately in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to separate rows like all affected rows which are same column value as "x", column value as "y" and so on..

For example: A table has a column name "Month". I want to show all affected rows which are for 'January', Which are for 'February' and by this I want to show rows  by their month name separately.

```
Sample Input:

title  month
 a      Jan
 b      Feb
 c      Feb
 d      Jan 
 e      Mar
 f      Jan
 g      Feb
 h      Jan
 i      Mar

Expected Output:

Jan:
    a 
    d
    f
    h
Feb:
   b
   c
   g
Mar:
   e
   i
```

I can not find any idea to solve this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: A couple of different approaches are possible, but I'd look at array_filter.

Comment: update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: What do you mean by affected rows? Re-phrase your ques..

Answer (score 0):

Without code, here's my best interpretation of what you're after.

You have some array and you want to split the array on one of the element values.

```
<?php

$array[0]['Month'] = 'January';
$array[0]['Activity'] = 'Sledding';
$array[1]['Month'] = 'January';
$array[1]['Activity'] = 'New years party';
$array[2]['Month'] = 'February';
$array[2]['Activity'] = 'Find a SO';
$array[3]['Month'] = 'February';
$array[3]['Activity'] = 'Celebrate Valentines';

$january = array_filter($array, function($item){
    return $item['Month'] === 'January';
});

$february = array_filter($array, function($item){
    return $item['Month'] === 'February';
});

echo "Jan:";
var_dump($january);

echo "\n\nFeb:";
var_dump($february);
```

**Yields:**

```
Jan:array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(7) "January"
    ["Activity"]=>
    string(8) "Sledding"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(7) "January"
    ["Activity"]=>
    string(15) "New years party"
  }
}


Feb:array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(8) "February"
    ["Activity"]=>
    string(9) "Find a SO"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(8) "February"
    ["Activity"]=>
    string(20) "Celebrate Valentines"
  }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a86fb26f3a619dff8fd7649f992ba9d6af38b9b5

Comment: Actually I want from mysql query

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure why you tagged it PHP if you were only looking for query help.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
select 
month, title
from
<table>
order by month;
```

This will give you month's title together.

```
Month    Title
Jan      a
Jan      d
Jan      f
Jan      h
Feb      b
Feb      c
Feb      g
Mar      e
Mar      i
```

Comment: this will give you month wise titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY Month
```

would be a valid qwery, however. if you want something like your example you've added, you could list the distinct items in the month colum first, and as it loops the first result of listing distintly, show the rows of the first result.

This would be done like:

```
   <?php
         @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Month from Table1";
  $result = $db->query($query); 

  while ($data = $result->fetch_row()) {
   echo '<table align="left"><tr>';
  for ($j=0; $j<$result->field_count; $j++) {
    echo '<th>'.$data[$j].': </th><tr><td>';
       $rowquery = "SELECT title from Table1 where Month='".$data[$j]."'";
        $rowresult = $db->query($rowquery); 
       echo '<table >';  
         while ($rowdata = $rowresult->fetch_row()) {
          echo '<tr align="right">';
                for ($k=0; $k<$rowresult->field_count; $k++) {
                echo '<td>'.$rowdata[$k].'</td>';
         }
         echo '</tr>';
         }
         echo '</table>';    

        }
         echo '</td></tr></table>';
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: I changed my answer to match the example that was added to the question

Answer (score 0):

this what i can do without seeing your code

```
$array = array( 
 'a' =>      'Jan',
 'b'   =>   'Feb',
 'c'   =>   'Feb',
 'd'   =>   'Jan', 
 'e'   =>   'Mar',
 'f '   =>  'Jan',
 'g'    =>  'Feb',
 'h'    =>  'Jan',
 'i'   =>   'Mar'
              );
$result=array();              
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    if(array_key_exists($value,$result)){
        $result[$value] .= ','.$key;
    } else {
        $result[$value] = $key;
    }
}
```

and this is the output

```
Array
(
    [Jan] => a,d,f ,h
    [Feb] => b,c,g
    [Mar] => e,i
)
```